# AD Banner Views and iOS 7/Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios7

I upgraded my iphone software to iOS 7 and I noticed that the ad banners in my free apps are barely showing up (extremely low fill rate). Does anybody know a solution to this problem? I'm using the iAD Network.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: It could just be that Apple's servers are swamped today. You might wait a day or two to see if it fixes itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are they just being overlapped by the navigation and toolbars? In that case you will need to update your layouts to handle the new edge-to-edge approach to content in iOS 7.

If the problem is only that they are no longer filling then that is something you should report to iAd. There may be compatibility issues with iOS 7 or they may be experiencing some other performance issues.